# Extract elements from nested list, and add as a new column of (nested) dataframes using purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I cannot seem to figure out the purrr syntax for extracting information from a nested list of results, and placing a tibble of results as a new column (of nested tibbles) of the main tibble.

```
library(EnvStats)
library(tidyverse)

    #create example dataset
    df1 <- tibble(
      Site=rep(c("Site1", "Site2"), 3, each=12),
      Month=rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), 6),
      Year=rep(c(2010, 2011, 2012), 2, each=12), 
      Value=sample(seq(from=0, to=20, by=.1), size=72, replace=TRUE)
    )

    df1 <- df1 %>% nest(-Site)

    res <- mutate(
      df1, 
      sk = map(data, ~ {
        EnvStats::kendallSeasonalTrendTest(.x$Value, season = .x$Month, 
                                           year = .x$Year)
      }))
```

Structure of main tibble, and the nested list of results (truncated):

```
  glimpse(res)

    Observations: 2 Variables: 3    
    $ Site <chr> "Site1", "Site2"    
    $ data <list> [<tbl_df[36 x 3]>, <tbl_df[36 x 3]>]    
    $ sk   <list> [<4.9772727, 0.3049971, 11, 0.9322623, 0.7603683,   

    glimpse(res$sk)

    List of 2    
    $ :List of 15     
      ..$ estimate : Named num [1:3] -0.222 -1.2 1766.625
      .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "tau" "slope" "intercept"
      ...more here 
    $ :List of 15          
        ..$ estimate : Named num [1:3] -0.222 -1.2 1766.625
        .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "tau" "slope" "intercept"
```

I can extract results from the sk lists and place as a new column in the main tibble.  For example:

```
#function to extract slope from a sk list
slope1 <- function(x) x$estimate[["slope"]]

#how to get results from nested list as a column in the main dataframe
ex1 <- res %>%  mutate(
      tau = map_dbl(sk, ~.x$estimate[["tau"]]),     
      slope = map_dbl(sk, slope1)
)

glimpse(ex1)

Observations: 2
Variables: 5
$ Site         <chr> "Site1", "Site2"
$ data         <list> [<tbl_df[36 x 3]>, <tbl_df[36 x 3]>]
$ sk           <list> [<4.9772727, 0.3049971, 11, 0.9322623, 0.7603683, 0.08333333, 0.47500000, -445.02500000, 0, 0,...
$ tau          <dbl> 0.08333333, -0.22222222
$ annual_slope <dbl> 0.475, -1.200
```

But I cannot figure out the syntax to extract results from the sk lists into a new dataframe, and attach that dataframe as a new column (1 df for each Site) in the main res dataframe.

Looking for the res df to end up with a new EnvOut column as shown below:

```
$ Site         <chr> "Site1", "Site2"  
$ data         <list> [<tbl_df[36 x 3]>, <tbl_df[36 x 3]>]  
$ sk           <list> [<4.9772727, 0.3049971, 11, 0.9322623, 0.7603683,   
$ EnvOut       <list> [<tbl_df[A x B]>, …
```

The following doesn't work...It's likely an issue the purrr syntax but I cannot figure it out.

```
#Now - how to create new column in res of (nested) dataframes with results extracted from original nested sk lists

#The dt_fun function will give me the dataframe for a single list 
#--> how to add this as nested list of dataframe to the original res dataframe?? 

df_fun <- function(df){
  df <- tibble(
    tau=df$estimate[["tau"]], 
    slope=slope1(df)
  )
  df
}

test <- df_fun(res$sk[[1]])


ex2  <- res %>%   mutate(
  envOut = map(sk, ~ dt_fun(.x[[1]]))
)
```

**Edit:** 
Both ex2 and ex3 below following seem to work.  Also to add results to dataframe without creating an external function the ex4 below works.  Not sure it's the most efficient syntax - but it works.

```
ex2  <- res %>%   mutate(
  envOut = map(sk, ~ df_fun(.x))
)

ex3  <- mutate(res, 
  envOut = map(sk, df_fun)
)

ex4  <- res %>%   mutate(
    envOut = map(sk, ~ tibble(tau = .x$estimate[["tau"]], 
                              slope = slope1(.x))
))
```

Comment: one small thing is `dt_fun()` isn't defined, perhaps `df_fun()` is what you are looking to call in `ex2`

Comment: Looks like `mutate(res, envOut = map(sk, df_fun)` will give you what you want

Comment: @Nate - thanks.  Feeling pretty foolish for not catching the typo and for the simplicity of the solution.